# GCP (Google Cloud) VM - Can't send email via Python script with SMTP

Tags: python, email, google-cloud-platform, smtp, virtual-machine

So I set up a GCP VM with Ubuntu, from where I want to send regular reports through my mail provider with a python script. The smtp port is 587, and to my understanding the port was formerly closed in GCP environments but should now be available.

My script looks like this:

```
import smtplib,ssl
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from email import encoders
import time


timestr = time.strftime('(%Y-%m-%d)')
username='me@mydomain.de'
password='secretpw'
send_from = 'me@mydomain.de'
send_to = 'recipient@herdomain.com'
body = 'hello'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = send_from
msg['To'] = send_to
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime = True)
msg['Subject'] = 'important email'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.ionos.de')
port = '587'
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.ionos.de')
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login(username,password)
smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to.split(','), msg.as_string())
smtp.quit()
```

On execution, the machine takes some time before outputting a timeout:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.ionos.de')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 310, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

I can, however, `ping smtp.ionos.de` as well as `telnet smtp.ionos.de 587` form the cl with result of a working ping and connection.

I also tried this with other email providers including gmail and get stuck with the exact same outcome.

Anyone? Help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: in cloud function put import smtplib and import ssl on 2 separate lines then follow John Hanley's suggestion below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems:

- Connecting to the server twice.
- Not specifying the port number when connecting
- Not creating an SSL context for encryption.

**In your code, replace these lines:**

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.ionos.de')
port = '587'
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.ionos.de')
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
```

**With:**

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.ionos.de', 587)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls(context=context)
```

Comment: wow, john this is great, because it works. thank you. but why did my version work flawlessly in my local python environment?

Comment: @janko I am guessing that the remote server is listening on port 25 which you can connect to with your local environment but in Google Cloud, you cannot as port 25 is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example tested with a GCP Cloud Function.  No libs are needed in requirements.txt.  This uses Python 3.9.  The code uses an [App Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) because normal users require 2FA.

```
import smtplib
import ssl

def send_email(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    gmail_user = 'user@gmail.com'
    gmail_password = 'YOURPASSWORD'

    sent_from = gmail_user
    to = ['foo@bar.com']
    subject = 'Test e-mail from Python'
    body = 'Test e-mail body'

    email_text = """\
    From: %s
    To: %s
    Subject: %s
    %s
    """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, body)
    server.close()
    print('Email sent (print)!')
    return f'Email sent (return)!'
```